# DateField's DateInput widget with 'format="%B"' is not localized/translated

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, localization

I have an UpdateView and when I visit the edit page, my date field renders the month as non-localized.

In my Form I'm using format("%B %Y") to have the full month + year representation, like so:

```
class CampaignForm(ModelForm):
    date = DateField(widget=DateInput(attrs={"autocomplete": "off"}, format="%B %Y"))
```

I'm using the form in a basic UpdateView setup, and I render the template...

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group flatpickrdatetimeinput col-md-6 mb-0">
        {{ form.date|as_crispy_field }}
    </div>
</div>
```

The date representation works in terms of month + year, but I need to localize the month name to the local language.
I cannot find the error, I tried changing the field attribute ([localize=True](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/formatting/#locale-aware-input-in-forms)) and also I have played around with the settings (i18n, l10n, etc) with no success.
In fact, the settings have worked out so far. In the same template I am using the 'date' template filter and it translates the month just fine

```
<h2>{{campaign.date | date:'F Y' }}</h2>
```

How to make use of the internal django localization inside a form/form-field?

Answer (score 1):

While writing the question, I had the idea to try to set the initial data and localize it there.
It indeed worked but it's a workaround and I still think it should work directly from the form.
If you have a solution please feel free to add it. Or leave a comment if you have experienced the issue and you think this is a bug.

```
from django.utils import formats

class CampaignUpdateView(CampaignMixin, UpdateView):

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super().get_initial()
        initial.update({"date": formats.date_format(self.object.date, format="F Y", use_l10n=True)})
        return initial
```